# Encoding or Decoding a text: Problem displaying output

Tags: java

This is an assignment given to me for encoding or decoding a text. My problem is that when I execute the functions separately, each function works fine, but when I combine them into a single class, the final output is not shown. Below is my code (I apologize for my messy code):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Encode_Decode
{
    public void decode(String text, int shift) //Function to decode a text.
    { 
        StringBuffer result= new StringBuffer(); //Creating StringBuffer object.

        for (int i=0; i<text.length(); i++) 
        { 
            if(text.charAt(i)=='K' && text.charAt(i+1)=='K') //If a pair of adjacent K's (KK) is found, it is replaced with a single blank space.
            {
                result.append(" "); //Replacing KK with single blank space.
                i++;
            }
            else
            { 
                char ch = (char)(((int)text.charAt(i) + shift - 65) % 26 + 65); //Replacing each letter with the letter 'n' ASCII values after it.
                result.append(ch); 
            } 
        }
        System.out.println("Decoded String: "+result); //Displaying the decoded string.
    }

    public void encode(String text, int shift) //Function for encode a text.
    {
        StringBuffer result= new StringBuffer(); //Creating StringBuffer object.

        for(int i=0; i<text.length(); i++)
        {
            if(text.charAt(i)==' ') //Replacing a single blank space with KK.
            {
                result.append("KK");
            }
            else
            {
                char ch = (char)(((int)text.charAt(i)+65-(shift)) % 26 + 65); //Replacing each letter with the letter 'n' ASCII values before it.
                result.append(ch); 
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Encoded string: "+result); //Displaying the encoded text.
    }

    public void Caesardecode(String text)
    {
        StringBuffer result= new StringBuffer();
        for(int i=0;i<text.length();i++)
        {
            if(text.charAt(i)==' ')
            {
                result.append(' ');
            }
            else
            {
                char ch = (char)(((int)text.charAt(i) + 13 - 65) % 26 + 65); 
                result.append(ch); 
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Decoded text: "+result);
    }

    public void Caesarencode(String text)
    {  
        StringBuffer result= new StringBuffer();
        for(int i=0;i<text.length();i++)
        {
            if(text.charAt(i)==' ')
            {
                result.append(' ');
            }
            else
            {
                char ch = (char)(((int)text.charAt(i)+65-13) % 26 + 65);
                result.append(ch); 
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Encoded text: "+result);
    }

    public void main()
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter: 1 for Normal Decoding."+"\n"+" 2 for Caesar Cipher Decoding."+"\n"+" 3 for Normal Encoding."+"\n"+" 4 for Caesar Cipher Encoding.");
        int choice=sc.nextInt();
        switch(choice)
        {
            case(1):
            System.out.println("Enter the text to be Decoded:");
            String s=sc.nextLine();
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter Shift Value:");
            int n=sc.nextInt();
            encode(s,n);
            break;

            case(2):
            System.out.println("Enter the text to be Decoded:");
            String s2=sc.nextLine();
            Caesardecode(s2);
            break;

            case(3):
            System.out.println("Enter the text to be Encoded:");
            String s3=sc.nextLine();
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter Shift Value:");
            int n3=sc.nextInt();
            encode(s3,n3);
            break;

            case(4):
            System.out.println("Enter the text to be Encoded:");
            String s4=sc.nextLine();
            Caesarencode(s4);
            break;

            default:
            System.out.println("WRONG CHOICE! TRY AGAIN!");
        }
    }
}
```

For example, when I combine them into a class, and then execute, following happens. As you can see, the decoded string is not shown, and the execution just ends.
[image]

Yet, when I execute the exact same function separately, then the output shows up as expected.
[image]

Once again, I apologize for my messy code. I would like some help to solve this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling first `sc.nextLine()` and then storing it in variable `s`.
It is required as you have previously called `sc.nextInt()`.
Change your code in `case(1)` to below:

```java
System.out.println("Enter the text to be Decoded:");
sc.nextLine();
String s=sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter Shift Value:");
int n=sc.nextInt();
decode(s,n);
```

Also, you are calling `encode()` function in `case(1)` instead of `decode()`.

Answer (score 0):

Lets understand the complete situation(Apart from typo mistake that you used encode(s,n); instead of decode(s,n); in case 1)

1) What you are seeing on *Terminal screen has both Input Stream and Output stream data.*

2)Your scanner is reading Input stream.When you write anything on the Input stream and **press enter it appends "/n" i.e new line character to your Input stream.**

3) Lets Understand what nextLine(), nextInt() does internally:

```
a) nextInt() - Scans the input stream till it finds Integer value.Then it stops the cursor there. 
b) nextLine() - Returns all the remaining data in the current line i.e data before /n  and positions the cursor at beginning of the next line.
```

4) When your program is started , All the info consists of Output stream Data like the menu options you provided.

> Current Input Stream and Cursor -- Empty. Scanner Cursor is at beginning `|`

5) You wrote 1 and then pressed Enter.

> Current Input Stream and Cursor -- `|`1 **/n** (i.e **1** and a new line character **"/n"** with scanner cursor at the beginning)

6) nextInt() read the input stream till it found the integer value i.e 1 and stops the cursor.

> Before Input Stream -- `|`1 **/n**
>
> After Input Stream -- 1`|`**/n** (i.e **1** and a new line character **"/n"** with scanner cursor after integer 1)
>
> Value of choice = 1

7) You wrote ZCQRKK.... and then pressed Enter.

> Current Input Stream -- 1`|`**/n**ZCQRKK.... **/n**
>
> (i.e 1 and a new line character **"/n"** and ZCQRKK.... a new line character **"/n"**  with scanner cursor after 1)

8) nextLine() Reads the remaining data in the current line i.e data after the cursor and before the first **"/n"**.The String entered as text to be decoded is placed after the /n and hence is not stored in variable s

> Before Input Stream and Cursor -- 1`|`**/n**ZCQRKK.... **/n**
>
> After Input Stream and Cursor -- 1 /n`|`ZCQRKK.... (i.e **1** and a new line character **"/n"** with scanner cursor at beginning of new line which has ZCQRKK....)
>
> Value of s = ""

To avoid this you have to move the cursor at beginning of the new line first before reading the input stream and saving the data to variable s.

So order of events should be

> a) choice = sc.nextInt() --> Movement of cursor `|`1 /n to 1`|`/n
>
> b) sc.nextLine() ---> Movement of cursor 1`|`/nZCQRKK....\n to 1
>   /n`|`ZCQRKK....\n
>
> c) s = sc.nextLine() -----> Movement of cursor 1/n`|`ZCQRKK...\n. to 1
>   /nZCQRKK....\n`|` and variable s has value "ZCQRKK..." now